# How to over lap a child element over the parent element

Tags: html, css

I have an `<li>` element which contains an unordered list. The unordered list is display when the user hovers over the parent `<li>` element. Recently there was a bordered added to the `<li>` and child `<ul>` elements and the `<li>` does not have a bottom border. I would like to hide the child unordered list top border behind the bottom of the `<li>` so that it will cut off the border of the unordered list for the section.

Here is a fiddle I created - http://jsfiddle.net/EZRU9/3/

Please note that this is close to the original implementation. I tried changing the parent `<li>` to have absolute position but that did not work and I changed it back. I may have done something else wrong when I tried that but since I changed it back, I created the fiddle to mimic what I currently have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a parent in front of the child with z-indexes. My advice in this case: add an extra element inside the `<li>`, give it `position: absolute;` and a background-color matching yours, then position it to cover part of the `<ul>` border.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the top level text ('Tab 1') in a span or other tag of your choosing. Then you can style and stack as desired.